# Переписывает значение в ключе

Tags: python-3.x, словари

Почему при открытии файла он переписывает значение, которые были добавлены на прошлом шаге, а в конечном итоге в ключ points передаёт последнюю строку из файла?

Первый шаг:

```
{'100': {'question': 'plane', 'answer': 'самолёт', 'asked': 'False'}}`
```

Второй шаг:

```
{'100': {'question': 'train', 'answer': 'поезд', 'asked': 'False'}, 
 '200': {'question': 'train', 'answer': 'поезд', 'asked': 'False'}}
```

(переписал прошлое значение ключа 100, хотя я обращаюсь к ключу 200)

```
def load_question():
    qwestions = {}
    mean = {}
    display = {}
    with (open("qwestions.txt", encoding='utf-8') as file):
        for word in file:
            if word.count(' ') < 2 and word != '\n':
                key = word.rstrip()
                #print(key)
            elif word.count(' ') == 3:
                points, question, answer, asked = word.rstrip().split(' ')
                display['question'] = question
                display['answer'] = answer
                display["asked"] = asked
                mean[points] = display
                qwestions[key] = mean
                print(points)
                print(mean)
                #print(qwestions)
            else:
                continue

    print(qwestions)
```

Пример файла `qwestions.txt`:

> ```
> Транспорт
> 100 plane самолёт False
> 200 train поезд False
> 300 boarding посадка False
> Животные
> 100 dog собака False
> 200 shark акула False
> 300 sparrow воробей False
> Еда
> 100 apple яблоко False
> 200 berry ягода False
> 300 venison оленина False
> ```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш вопрос пример вашего файла `qwestions.txt`, чтобы ваш вопрос не был закрыт. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Транспорт

100 plane самолёт False
200 train поезд False
300 boarding посадка False

Животные

100 dog собака False
200 shark акула False
300 sparrow воробей False

Еда

100 apple яблоко False
200 berry ягода False
300 venison оленина False

Comment: Пожалуйста, не в комментарии, а прямо в вопросе (клик на Править под вопросом) - здесь не видно отдельные строки файла.

Answer (score 0):

##### *Анализ:*

У вас 3 уровня словарей:

- главный (итоговый), которой вы называете `qwestions`
  (правильно по-английски бы хотелось **questions**),
- средний (по темам, как Транспорт или Животные) - вы его называете `mean`
  (хотелось бы **middle**, т.к. mean означает статистическое среднее значение),
- внутренний (вопросы по данной теме), который вы называете `display`.

**Ошибка** в вашем коде состоит в том, что кроме главного словаря,

**словари остальных уровней нужно в правильный момент обнулять**.

Именно

- средний при появлении **нового ключа**,
- внутренний при появлении **нового вопроса**.

---

##### *Исправление:*

Команды

```
mean = {}
display = {}
```

из начала вашей программы нужно *переместить в правильные места*:

- первую в вашу ветвь `if` (т.е. при появлении *нового ключа*),
- вторую в `elif` (т.е. при появлении *нового вопроса*),

вот так:

```
        ...
        if word.count(' ') < 2 and word != '\n':
            mean = {}
            key = word.rstrip()
            #print(key)
        elif word.count(' ') == 3:
            display = {}
            points, question, answer, asked = word.rstrip().split(' ')
            ...
```

---

*Результат (словарь `qwestions`) - я использовал стандартный модуль [pprint](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/library/pprint.html) для его вывода:*

```
{'Транспорт': {'100': {'question': 'plane', 'answer': 'самолёт', 'asked': 'False'},
               '200': {'question': 'train', 'answer': 'поезд', 'asked': 'False'},
               '300': {'question': 'boarding', 'answer': 'посадка', 'asked': 'False'}},
 'Животные':  {'100': {'question': 'dog', 'answer': 'собака', 'asked': 'False'},
               '200': {'question': 'shark', 'answer': 'акула', 'asked': 'False'},
               '300': {'question': 'sparrow', 'answer': 'воробей', 'asked': 'False'}},
 'Еда':       {'100': {'question': 'apple', 'answer': 'яблоко', 'asked': 'False'},
               '200': {'question': 'berry', 'answer': 'ягода', 'asked': 'False'},
               '300': {'question': 'venison', 'answer': 'оленина', 'asked': 'False'}}}
```